# How can i give div background color based on count with differences of 3 within while loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I have a div with several boxes within while loop. I want to give the two alternative div background color. For first 3 boxes i have to give the first color. Then for next 3 boxes i'v to give next color, then again for the next 3 boxes i'v to give the first color and so on.

Clearly i want to give the two colors alternatively for 3 boxes alternatively from first. Can anyone help me for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var count=0;
 $("div").each(function (i) {
         count++;
        if (count%3) {
          this.style.color = "blue";
        } else {
          this.style.color = "black";
        }
      });
```

Comment: if we give (count/2) means it will be applied to alternative boxes next to each other. But I want to give div bgcolor for first three boxes and the next three boxes the bgcolor should be diff then for the next three boxes the color should be same as the first one and so on

Comment: Question was tagged PHP, why are you answering with JavaScript jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count=0;
if(count%2==0) {
 echo"<div style="background:white;">";
}
else {
echo"<div style="background:pink;">";
}
echo"</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired result is:

```
<div class="white">...
<div class="white">...
<div class="white">...
<div class="blue">...
<div class="blue">...
<div class="blue">...
<div class="white">...
```

Which mean your code should be:

```
for ($count = 0 ; $count < 20; $count++) {
    $color = ($count / 3) % 2 ? "blue" : "white";
    echo "<div class='$color'>", "SOMETHING", "</div>";
}
```

All you're doing is grouping "dividing by 3" then determining if the group is even or odd.

Note: You could easily use a `style="background-color:$color"` depending on your needs and CSS info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think he likes this is JS as his tag is PHP

is this what you are looking for;

```
<div>
<?php
   $numberofResults = '5';   
   for ($i=1; $i<=$numberofResults; $i++){
         if($i % 2 == 0) $style='style="background-color:black"';
         else $style='style="background-color:white"';

         echo '<box'.$i.' ' . $style . '>';
         echo '</box'.$i.'>';
         echo "\n";
   }
?>
</div>
```

this will yield;

```
<div>
    <box1 style="background-color:white"></box1>
    <box2 style="background-color:black"></box2>
    <box3 style="background-color:white"></box3>
    <box4 style="background-color:black"></box4>
    <box5 style="background-color:white"></box5>
</div>
```